# How do I use an external data source in a view?

Tags: views

I am trying to display some TV schedule information from a thirdparty json api.
I need to know what is the best way to do this.
I have tried various module wsclient module,json query plugin, wsclient view integration. But none of them worked and overkill.

I can write a module to do this, but I need some information. One option I was thinking off was making a new data source available to the Views module. What hooks need to implemented for this?

Comment: Are you trying to pull in the data and save it to drupal or just pull and display it?

Comment: Just pull in and display. saving wouldnt make sense as it change very often.

Comment: I would suggest just creating a custom module and a custom page using hook_menu.  ANd just make your call during the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Views JSON Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_json_query).

> JSON Query is a Views 3 plugin that adds native JSON query generation.
>   It allows you to parse JSON using Views' graphical query builder. It
>   works much like Views XML Backend but with JSON.

Comment: I have tried that. It doesnt output anything. I am using this api call as json source http://mta.tv:8080/broadcast/schedule.svc/nowshowing